# Visual Studio 2013 intellisense quick info missing while typing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, visual-studio-2013

I have VS2013 and Resharper

Today for a reason unknown to me I no longer get the helpful hover window that describes the method I have selected from the list of methods.

For example, if I typed

```
Console.WriteLine
```

I would get a box detailing what WriteLine did / parameters etc.

If I return on WriteLine and hover my mouse over it, it still describes WriteLine. I found the detail while typing very useful.

I've repaired resharper
disabled and enabled intellisense 
disabled and enabled statement completion

How do I get it back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check you have the following checkboxes ticked:

1. ReSharper | Options | Environment | IntelliSense | Completion Appearance | Show Summary
2. ReSharper | Options | Environment | IntelliSense | Parameter Info | Automatically show parameter info...

Comment: Show Summary wasn't ticked. Thank you.